# how to resolve this hyperledger curl command error?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

```
$ curl -sSL https | bash
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 1: `<HTML>'
```

there is a url ahead of https but i cant write it:-goo.gl/pabwjx

Comment: please add a similar-looking url with the hostname replaced by example.com. the referenced goo.gl url didn't resolve. hint: there's an "edit" button

Answer (score 0):

Use escape characters. There are multiple characters which are interpreted by the shell, so entering a URL without escaping is usually dangerous.

Often used bad caracters are: `&` and `?`

bad example:

```
curl -sSL https://example.com/abc?param=x&param2=y
```

(Result: `curl -sSL https://example.com/abc?param=x` runs as a background command, `param2=y` runs as a foreground command)

good examples:

```
curl -sSL "https://example.com/abc?param=x&param2=y"
curl -sSL 'https://example.com/abc?param=x&param2=y'
curl -sSL https://example.com/abc\?param=x\&param2=y
```

**WARNING:**

Directly executing a download by a shell is even more dangerous than the above if the content provider (server) is not operated by you.